# Passing series data from Java to Multi Y axis Highcharts

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have just started learning JQuery and Highcharts. I created a multi Y-axis highchart with static data. I wanna be able to pass data from java to the series data. How do i do it? How do i make the JQuery code to fetch data from my java class and load it into the highcharts. The following is my code:

```
// MultiY.js
$(document).ready(function() {


    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart_1',
        height: 350,
     },
     title: {
        text: 'Sample Highcharts'
     },
     xAxis: {
        categories: ['4/28/2013', '4/29/2013', '4/30/2013', '5/1/2013', '5/2/2013', '5/3/2013', '5/4/2013']      
     },
     yAxis: [{
         opposite: true,
         title: {
             text: 'Cost',
             style: {
                 color: '#dbf400'
             }             
         },
         labels: {
             style: {
                 color: '#dbf400'
             }
         },plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 20
            }
        }
     },
     {
         lineWidth: 2,
         title: {
             text: 'Silver',
             style: {
                 color: '#89A54E'
             }
         },
         labels: {
             style: {
                 color: '#89A54E'
             }
         }
     }, {
         lineWidth: 2,
         opposite: true,
         title: {
             text: 'Gold',
             style: {
                 color: '#4572A7'
             }
         },
         labels: {
             style: {
                 color: '#4572A7'
             }
         }
     }, {
         lineWidth: 2,
         opposite: true,
         title: {
             text: 'Score',
             style: {
                 color: '#AA4643'
             }
         },
         labels: {
             style: {
                 color: '#AA4643'
             }
         }
     }],

     series: [ {
         name: 'Cost',
         type: 'column',
         color: '#dbf400',
         data: [65078.70, 70816.51, 71211.22, 56130.71, 67839.10, 59170.91, 52826.47] ,
         yAxis: 3
     }, {
         name: 'Silver',
         type: 'spline',
         color: '#89A54E',
         dashStyle: 'shortdot',
         data: [6357434, 7190915, 6737487, 6001323, 8628154, 7446175, 5953040]        
     }, {
         name: 'Gold',
         type: 'spline',
         color: '#4572A7',
         data: [2652304, 2862748, 2645867, 2506507, 2531869, 2352410, 2127584] ,
         yAxis: 1
     }, {
         name: 'Score',
         type: 'spline',
         color: '#AA4643',
         data: [57994, 68114, 64582, 26526, 52712, 55464, 46802] ,
         yAxis: 2
     }]
    });

});
```

My Java function returns:

```
trendingData.add(new TrendingDataObjects(silver, gold, score, cost, day));
```

Comment: I think you may do this in that way: 1) use AJAX, from jQuery may be or get() or getJSON(). I advice to use second. 2) On your Java class add library to export to JSON, and encode to that format. 3) Connect AJAX request to URL which will return that JSON. 4) To add new series use [chart.addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()) or to set new data for existing series use [chart.series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData())

Comment: I followed ur advice. I wrote a ajax function and got the json data. i tried to create the series data by using :
' success: function(data){
         chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.timestamp);
         chart.addSeries({
                name: "Cost",
                data: data.cost
         });'
But now the chart is not loading :(

Comment: data.timestamp should be an array of strings (example: `['a','b','c']`), and data.cost should be an array of points (example: `[123,145,156]`). Are you sure that is your JSON format for data? Could you show sample of your JSON data?

Comment: Here's the sample json data: 
'"[gold:[5395767.0, 6528407.0, 5575399.0], silver:[2366743.0, 2544655.0, 2471417.0], score:[53074.0, 62970.0, 61518.0], cost:[54818.32023, 62942.808914, 58198.033533], timestamp:[2013-06-02, 2013-06-03, 2013-06-04]]"
'

Comment: This is not proper JSON, so probably AJAX success isn't called, test it with [parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and you will see. JSON has names like `"gold": [123, 123, 123]` and starts with `{` and ends with `}` Also, as I said - timestamps should be strings.

Comment: I have modified my java function to pkg the data this way: 
'map.put("score", score);
 map.put("cost", cost);
 map.put("gold", gold);
 map.put("silver", silver);
 map.put("timestamp", date);  
 write(response, map);' and then write it out by setting the contenttype to application/json and using Gson.toJson(map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: After the document.ready() .... make the ajax call and put the chart creation functionality within the success function. That way the chart would load with the data while initiation. Example:
// Once DOM (document) is finished loading
$(document).ready(function() {

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){


        var timeArray = data.time;
        var costArray = data.cost;


     // First chart initialization
        chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart_1',
            height: 350,
         },
         title: {
            text: 'Ozone Trending'
         },
         xAxis: {
           categories: timeArray,
           labels: {
               rotation: -45,
               align: 'right'
           }
         },
         yAxis: [{
             opposite: true,
             title: {
                 text: 'Cost'

             },
             labels: {
                 style: {
                     color: '#dbf400'
                 }
             },plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointWidth: 20
                }
            }
         }],

         series: [ {
             name: 'Cost',
             data: costArray,

         }]
        });


    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://wicked-charts.org. It's a Java library providing an API with which you can create a chart options object for Highcharts with any data you want, something like this:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.setChartOptions(
  new ChartOptions()
    .setRenderTo("chart_1")
    .setHeight(350));
// set all your other options, including axes and data points
```

Once you have that Java object that suits your needs, you can either pass it to a Wicket or JSD component (if you use one of these frameworks - see the project homepage for a howto) or you can directly create the JSON representation of your chart like this:

```
JsonRenderer renderer = new JsonRenderer();
String jsonString = renderer.toJson(options);
```

Comment: What wicket is doing, i have already done in my multiy.js. Like creating the axes and series. I just wanted to fetch the series data from the java class. I dont really see the advantage of using wicket here. I was thinking more like calling the java function from multiy.js and assigning the series data with the data fetched.

Comment: Okay, now I got your question. You want to call a Java function on a server from your jQuery code, right? In that case you need some server-side Java web application that you can access via HTTP and for example use jquery ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call it. A java web application you can build with Java frameworks like JSP, JSF, Wicket or Spring MVC, for example...