# How to Manipulate StringList to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

Let me thank you for your time first off.

**Project Setup:**

I am running Spring Framework with AngularJS as MVC.

**Goal:**

I want to gather tweets and visualize on UI using Highcharts or any other graphing libraries.

**Problem:**

I am getting tweets and I am able to print it on UI using *{{tweets}}* tag. But I just want to know how do I manipulate so that I can pass it to Javascript.

**This is my sample code:**

```
public static String getTwitterSentiment (String s)
{
..... //getting tweets here
    String str1 = output1.toString();
    String[] tweetset = str1.split("\n");
    List<String> tweetlist = Arrays.asList(tweetset);
    List<String> tweetlist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String e : tweetlist) 
    {
        String f = e.concat("qqq");
        tweetlist2.add(f);
    }
    String hmm = tweetlist2.toString();
    String yes = hmm.replace("qqq]", "]");
  return yes;
}
```

I am gathering tweets, storing it in `<String> list` and `concat with /qqq` so that every tweet will have *qqq* at the end. I would probably need to split it and pass them to charts on UI.

**Why?** Good question! I have tried *JSON-simple, Jackson, Play.json* plugin but for some reason, my values won't return the JSON value to UI. (I just get blank on UI) and *json-simple* seemed to be the culprit.

**UI (AngularJS):**

```
<tr ng-repeat="brand in brands">
    <td>{{brand.brand}}</td>
    <td>{{brand.brandDescription.brandDescription}}</td>
    <td>
```

I am printing everything in {{brands}}. This is my sample tweet.

**Sample Tweet (ON UI):** (**I added **** for easier understanding)

```
[I posted a new photo to Facebook http://t.co/wweGICjyOT**qqq**, positive**qqq**, 0.68992**qqq**, Good morning! Ready for another great day! http://t.co/uVNgRQjTGH**qqq**, positive**qqq**, 0.19851**qqq**, I posted a new photo to Facebook http://t.co/QDuHK8IrRN**qqq**, positive**qqq**, 0.68992**qqq**]
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module("sprang.services", ["ngResource"]).
factory('Brand', function ($resource) {
    var Brand = $resource('/api/brands/:brandId', {brandId: '@id'},
        {update: {method: 'PUT'}});
    Brand.prototype.isNew = function(){
        return (typeof(this.id) === 'undefined');
    }
    return Brand;
});

angular.module("sprang", ["sprang.services"]).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/brands', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/list.html', controller: BrandListController})
        .when('/brands/:brandId', {templateUrl: '/views/brands/detail.html', controller: BrandDetailController});
});

function BrandListController($scope, Brand) {
    $scope.brands = Brand.query();

    $scope.deleteBrand = function(brand) {
        brand.$delete(function() {
            $scope.brands.splice($scope.brands.indexOf(brand),1);
            toastr.success("Deleted");
        });
    }
}

function BrandDetailController($scope, $routeParams, $location, Brand) {
    var brandId = $routeParams.brandId;

    if (brandId === 'new') {
        $scope.brand = new Brand();
    } else {
        $scope.brand = Brand.get({brandId: brandId});
    }

    $scope.save = function () {
        if ($scope.brand.isNew()) {
            $scope.brand.$save(function (brand, headers) {
                alert("in save");
                toastr.success("Created");
                var location = headers('Location');
                var id = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                $location.path('/brands/' + id);
            });
        } else {
            $scope.brand.$update(function() {
                toastr.success("Updated");
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

I am fairly new to Javascript or AngularJS. **Please suggest me a way to organize the elements (or convert it to JSON on frontend) to display on highcharts.**

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing series data from Java to Multi Y axis Highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299828/passing-series-data-from-java-to-multi-y-axis-highcharts)